# A variant of Buchholz's ordinal notation

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, lo.logic, linear-orders

Buchholz [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168007286900527?via%3Dihub) introduced an ordinal notation, consisting of a set $\mathcal{T}$, a linear order $\prec$ on $\mathcal{T}$ and some $\mathcal{OT} \subset \mathcal{T}$ such that $(\mathcal{OT}, \prec)$ is a well-ordered set. Also, Buchholz defined an order-preserving surjection $o$ mapping $\mathcal{T}$ onto the hull $C_0(\varepsilon_{\Omega_\omega+1})$ so that $o \upharpoonright \mathcal{OT}$ is injective.

Furthermore, [in another paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.573.420&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Buchholz defined an expansion rule $[]: \mathcal{T}^2 \to \mathcal{T}$ and some $\mathrm{dom}: \mathcal{T} \to \mathcal{T}$ so that $(\mathcal{OT}, [])$ is isomorphic to $(\mathscr{H}, ())$ where $\mathscr{H}$ is a set of hydras and $()$ is Buchholz's rule for expanding them. Let $\Rightarrow$ be the smallest transitive relation so that, for all $s, t \in \mathcal{T}$, $\exists a \in \mathrm{dom}(s) (s[a] = t)$ implies $s \Rightarrow t$.

Then, if we define $\mathcal{UT} = \{s \in \mathcal{T}: \forall t \in \mathcal{T} (s \Rightarrow t \rightarrow o(t) < o(s))\}$, is $(\mathcal{UT}, \prec)$ well-founded? If not, what are some extra conditions we could add, in terms of only $\Rightarrow$ and not things like Buchholz's $C$-sets, to ensure well-foundedness?

Comment: Is $\mathcal{UT}$ related to the set $T_0$ that Buchholz defines after Proposition 3 (p.137) in "An Independence Result for $(\Pi_1^1-CA)+BI$"?

Comment: They might be somehow related, but they're not defined too similarly, as the definition of $T_0$ doesn't utilize $[]$ as far as I know.

Comment: I was going to write an answer about "[Relating ordinals to proofs in a perspicuous way](https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~buchholz/articles/f7june.pdf)", which defines the ordinal notation system $(\mathrm T,\prec)$ and then gives a system of fundamental sequences for it. Its theorem 1.5(d) is very close to what you want, if not exact. But the single most important case of the fund. seq. system looks a bit different than the definition hydra expansion, so unfortunately I don't think it applies...